# How to change Opera language back to English?

Tags: languages, opera-mini

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I set the language in Opera Mini 6?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/how-can-i-set-the-language-in-opera-mini-6)

I installed Opera in a Samsung Galaxy Y. Since probably it detected that I'm in the Philippines, the language defaults to Filipino. How do I change it to English?

Comment: Related: [How can I set the language in Opera Mini 6?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/7932/how-can-i-set-the-language-in-opera-mini-6)